# How to experimentally distinguish Nematic transition versus Jahn-Teller distortion?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, symmetry-breaking

Both nematic transition and Jahn-Teller distortion distorts the lattice and reduces the symmetry of a crystal; both of the structure transition can take place at higher temperature than the magnetic transition.

Why in iron-based superconductors it is called nematic transition, while in molecular system it is called Jahn-Teller effect? (Particularly in the papers talk about iron-based superconductor they never talk about Jahn-Teller effect.) Is there a deterministic experimental fact to distinguish the two?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They are very similar ideas. The Jahn-teller effect can be thought of as symmetry breaking where a structural distortion breaks the degeneracy of some orbitals.

(Electronic) Nematicity is a more general concept, referring to any situation where the electronic fluid spontaneously breaks the rotational symmetry of the lattice, which necessarily will also induce a symmetry lowering structural distortion. This can be driven by different degrees of freedom. For example, in the spin degree of freedom, a melting of an anisotropic spin density wave can give rise to anisotropic magnetic fluctuations which induce an electronic nematic phase. However, the charge degrees of freedom can also drive the nematic transition, where the on-site energies and occupations of symmetry degenerate orbitals become different. This case of an electronic nematic phase driven by the charge degrees of freedom is very much in the spirit (similar to) the Jahn-Teller effect.

Comment: Hi pmal, thank you for answering my question! Let me try to rephrase your exlanation: The Jahn-Teller effect is a structure-distortion-driven symmetry-breaking; while nematicity is an charge-driven symmetry breaking. So the key difference here is "which one is the driving factor". Then can I make the following statement:  if a systems displays anisotropy in both structure, spin and charge degree of freedom, but we cannot distinguish which comes first, then we cannot tell if it is a Jahn-Teller distortion or a nematic phase. Is this statement correct?